# parallelogram equation in euclidean spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show that normed space is euclidean space iff for any $x$ and $y$ perform parallelogram equation, i.e $||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2=2(||x||^2+||y||^2)$. I proved this one way. in the opposite direction, I take $(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2)$ and I proved the linearity, but I have some problem with proving that $(\lambda x,y)=\lambda(x,y)$. Firsly we can easly prove that for $-1$ and by induction that this is done $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb Z$ and therefore $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb N$.(This follows from linearity). I'm also already proof that $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb Q$, but I have some problems to prove this for irrational $\lambda$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $x,y$ the function $\lambda \mapsto \langle \lambda x,y\rangle- \lambda \langle x,y \rangle$ is continuous, and you've proved it's $0$ on a dense set.

Comment: We can take a function $\lambda\to\frac{1}{\lambda}(\lambda x,y)$? This function defined on $\mathbb R/\{0\}$ are equal $(x,y)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb Q/\{0\}$ and then for any $\lambda \in \mathbb Q/\{0\}$.But how does it follow that it is defined for $\lambda \in \mathbb R/\{0\}$

Comment: I didn't say anything about $\frac{1}{\lambda}$  The function is the difference of two numbers that you've proved to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any real number $r$, take a sequence $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals converging to $r$ and use continuity.